# Tried adding a list of strings to code first entity framework class, now it really wants a IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

As an experiment I decided to add a list of strings to one of my entity framework classes, I ran 'Add-Migration MultiList' and got the error:

> Unable to create an object of type 'MediaEngineContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.

Removing the list didn't resolve the issue.

Looking online seems like a lot of people had this issue with older versions of .net core and upgrading fixed the issue, not for me so much..

Nothing else changed in my project, not how I start building things or anything like that.

Comment: *Removing the list didn't resolve the issue.* What do you mean? You had correct code. Added a list and got an exception. Removing the list should restore the faultless code, shouldn't it?

Comment: Take a look at [Upgrading applications from previous versions to EF Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade) section of the documentation, especially the **New way of getting application services** part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the package manager console to run Add-Migration/Update-Database. My start up project was not set to the project with the entity framework code, updating that fixed the issue.

Having the 'Default Project' in the PMC alone was not enough.